# IdentityServer4 & Asp.net Core Identity SignalR with bearer token

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm learning IdentityServer and asp.net core and I'm trying to use Asp.net Identity as a userstore.

The base setup is a SignalR Hub with a `Authorize` attribute and IdentityServer4.

If I use `AddTestUsers()` I can create an accesstoken with `ResourceOwnerPassword` and then connect to the SignalR Hub without problem.

If I add Asp.net Identity I still get legit accesstokens with `ResourceOwnerPassword` but the accesstoken is then somehow not used on the SignalR call. Instead I see in the serverlogs, that it uses a `CookieAuthenticationHandler` and tries to redirect to /account/login. Did I miss something here or did I misconfigure the pipeline?

Serverlog:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:53802/TestHub
>
> info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
>         Authorization failed.
>
> info:
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[12]
>         AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 63.6591ms 302
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:53802/account/login?returnUrl=%2FTestHub
>
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>         Request finished in 3.5257ms 404

ConfigureServices:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddIdentity<AppUser, ElCamino.AspNetCore.Identity.AzureTable.Model.IdentityRole>((options) =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            }).AddAzureTableStoresV2<ApplicationDbContext>(() =>
            {
               IdentityConfiguration idconfig = new IdentityConfiguration
                    {
                        TablePrefix = "v2",
                        StorageConnectionString = connectionString,
                        LocationMode = "PrimaryOnly"
                    };
                    return idconfig;
                })
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())   
                .AddAspNetIdentity<AppUser>();


            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "http://localhost:53802";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.ApiName = "api1";
                });
}
```

And this is Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
{
    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseSignalR(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapHub<TestHub>("/TestHub");
    });
}
```